# How to do IS NOT NULL in a Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to do this SQL statement and outputting it using the blade engine:

```
" SELECT SUM(like) FROM likes WHERE post_id = ". $post->id. " AND source_id IS NOT '' "
```

I don't know how to do it, I tried this yesterday but it didn't work:

```
{{$post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->where('source_id', '<>', '')->sum('like')}}
```

The *likes* table "belongsTo" both the *sources* table and the *posts* table.

**Edit:**

I'm using Laravel version **5.2.45**

Comment: Please specify the laravel version you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`whereNotNull()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.3/Query/Builder.php#L1041) method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

**Update**

It seems `$posts` is a collection. In this case, you'll have to use [`filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-filter). For example:

```
$collection->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item['some_value'] !== null;
});
```

Comment: I get the error message `ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method whereNotNull does not exist.` when I try that one.

Comment: I'm calling it like this from a view:

` <p>Total likes: {{ $post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->whereNotNull('source_id')->sum('like') }} </p> `

Comment: Offtopic : you should consider checking your datas in your controller instead that checking in your view.

Comment: It seems like this is working, thanks! Still gotta do some more testing though.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 4./5. its whereNotNull() and for Laravel 3: its where_not_null().

So your query will be this if version is Laravel 4./5.,

```
{{$post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->whereNotNull('source_id')->sum('like')}}
```

Query will be this if version is Laravel 3,

```
{{$post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->where_not_null('source_id')->sum('like')}}
```

Comment: I get the error message  `ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method whereNotNull does not exist.` when I try that one.

Comment: i tried with above query it's working. so please show me what you have tried you?

Comment: ` <p>Total likes:{{$post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->whereNotNull('source_id')->sum('like')}} </p> `

Sorry, the code enclosing seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: try with removing sum(like) from above query.

Comment: I still get the error `Method whereNotNull does not exist.`

Comment: Try with this normal query and double check the field names of your database because this error may be occurs due to field names error if it's perfect that try with this normal query in any other model and tell me below is giving the same error or not.
DB::table('name')->WhereNotNull('column')->get();

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this...

```
{{$post->likes->where('post_id', $post->id)->whereNotNull('source_id')->sum('like')}}
```

Also try as

```
{{$post->likes->
where([
    ['post_id', '=', $post_id],
    ['source_id', '<>', NULL],])
->sum('like') }}
```

Comment: There is no `where_not_null`, it's `whereNotNull()`

Comment: `source_id <> NULL` will never be TRUE.